# How to filter unwanted packages in android SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android SDK updater shows a lot of different system images. I don't need them all. Is there an option to check which packages I am interested to download in Android Studio

[image: screenshot]

However, I cannot uncheck any system position image (only Android Repository and Offline Repo can be unchecked).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think its important to clarify couple of things. Lets take your screenshot as base:

**SDK platforms**: It includes all android API. if any SDK platform installed .then it will be part of update-tracking.

**SDK Tools**: It includes developer tools. any checked one will be apart update-tracking.

**SDK Update sites**: It includes repositories for all resources.

If you don't want to get any update of any system image.. just don't install any image. Then You won't be notified about updates. Im pretty sure. You will get updates about what you have installed only.

If you still interested to uncheck `Android System Images`, do the following:

1. Launch SDK manager from **SDK platforms** by click on `Launch
   standalone SDK manager`
2. Go to menu under `Tools` and click on `Android Add-on Sites...`
3. Uncheck `Android System Images`
4. Close and that's it

If you cannot click on `Tools` in menu. Try to change focus to another window and get back to SDK Manager Window. It happens with me on Mac

[image: Android SDK Manager Add-on sites]

Good luck,'.

Comment: th eproble is. that there is no longer an option to launch standalone SDK manager ufter last update

Comment: you can,  call /home/yarh/android-sdk/tools/android    ( be sure you have proper credentials )

Comment: last update changed content of that file to #!/bin/bash
echo The "android" command is no longer available.
echo For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
echo For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
exit 1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Android Studio updater you can also use the command line sdkmanager which can be found at `your/path/to/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager`

With `sdkmanager --list` you can print a list of all available and install them with `sdkmanager "system-images;the_wanted_system_image"`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why your screenshot shows `SDK Update Sites` (it's place where you can pick sources of updates, not updates itself), but if you will pick `SDK Platforms` tab, then click check `Show Package Details` you will be able to pick whatever you want.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is the easiest way according to me
Open run and type

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images
```

and delete the unwanted system images from there Good Luck

Comment: there is nothing to delte, as i did not installed them. I just dont want to see them in sdk manger, so I can safly click new packages and dont have to worry that I will install system images

Comment: for that you can move those system images to another location